# expressjs api call to mongodb

Tags: json, mongodb, express

not quite sure where to start on this one.

I have an API call that returns a  mongodb response JSON when called. 
Below is a expressJS api call:

```
router.get("/getrodavail/beatcode/:beatCode([A-Z]
  {4})/weekstart/:weekstart/rods/:rods/days:days", function (req, res, next) {


 db.rodAvail.find({
     BeatCode: req.params.beatCode,
     WeekStartDisplay: req.params.weekstart,

     rods: req.params.rods,
     days: req.params.days,

 }, function (err, returnedResult) {
     if (err) {
         res.send(err);
         console.log(err);
         return;
     }
     res.json(returnedResult);
 });
});
```

And this is an example JSON/mongodb collection  it is to looking inside:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59dcda1c5ee14545ac453fcd"),
    "BeatCode" : "YOSP",
    "WeekStartDisplay" : "Oct 9th",
    "WeekStartDigits" : "171009",
    "WeekNo" : "1741",
    "OmnisWeekCode" : "200",
    "Currency" : "&pound;",
    "Rent" : "45",
    "Mon" : "-",
    "Tue" : "2",
    "Wed" : "4",
    "Thu" : "4",
    "Fri" : "4",
    "Sat" : "-",
    "Sun" : "2",
    "Notes" : "C&amp;R GX",
    "MinDays" : "1",
    "MinRods" : "1",
    "CatchLimits" : "0",
    "BoatHire" : "0",
    "OnLineBooking" : "1",
    "TicketName" : "Salmon+Trout",
    "SpeciesString" : "Atlantic Salmon Sea Trout",
    "SpeciesDisplay" : "as st"
}
```

As you can see, my api call sends in a rod and day parameter. My issue is how the heck do I go about mapping this rod/day to the actual fields it looking to use: Mon:0 Tue:2 and so forth.

The goal of the API is to return only those records that contain Mon/Tue/Wed > 1 (could be 6 for example)

Comment: So a number beside day (Mon, Tue Wed...) indicates the number of rods?

Comment: It does indeed, if rods:4, I need to check if Mon to Sunday in the JSON is >= 4 for example

Its pretty much an availability search

Comment: What does your `req.params.days` look like when you do `console.log(req.params.days);`?

Comment: its just a numerical value, 1 through 12.

Comment: Any thoughts anyone